# PriorityBinding like behavior in SortDescription for ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, listbox

I have to sort a `ListBox` by a departure date but when this date is null I have to sort the `ListBox` by the return date.

In my `SortDescription`I would need a `PriorityBinding` or a `FallBackValue` if the path is null.

Let's say I've 4 Trips. 3 Trips are of Type Outward and therefore have only Outward Dates.
One is of Return Type and have only a return date.

If I do the folllowing :

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="TripItems" Source="{Binding TripDatas}" >
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Outward.PlannedDate" />
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Return.PlannedDate" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

I'll have :

- Outward Date 10/01/2010
- Outward Date 11/01/2010
- Outward Date 12/01/2010
- Return Date 11/01/2010

And I want :

- Outward Date 10/01/2010
- Return Date 11/01/2010
- Outward Date 11/01/2010
- Outward Date 12/01/2010

Anyone could help?

Comment: Just sort by  departure date, return date

Comment: I'm sorry i wasn't clear enough I think, I updated the question.